# Authorization Basic HTTRIO SPC / Delphi

Tags: soap, authorization

**Bom dia a todos**,

Gostaria de saber se alguém poderia me ajudar na seguinte situação:

estou fazendo uma integração com o web service do SPC/CDL, o qual necessita uma autenticação do tipo basic (header do HTTP).

Preciso fazer essa autenticação utilizando o HTTRIO pois usei o Importer WSDL, não construi o XML na "unha", digamos assim.

Consegui realizar a autenticação no evento beforePost conforme exemplo abaixo:

```
  auth := 'Authorization: Basic ' + EncodeString('login:senha');
  HttpAddRequestHeaders(Data, PChar(auth), Length(auth), HTTP_ADDREQ_FLAG_ADD);
```

o problema é o seguinte, a primeira vez que executo a aplicação e consumo o web service, funciona perfeitamente, faz a autenticação e me da um retorno, tudo ok.

Porém, sem fechar a aplicação se realizar mais uma consulta, retorna o erro de autenticação (Erro Autenticação WS).

Se fechar a aplicação e abrir novamente a primeira consulta funciona.

Alguém poderia ajudar?

Segue fonte de um projeto que fiz aqui para teste:

```
procedure TForm3.BitBtn1Click(Sender: TObject);
var C:ConsultaSpcScWSService;
    F:filtroConsultaSpcPlusMasterProtestoSCWS2;
    R:RespostaConsultaSpcPlusMasterProtestoSC2;
    H:THTTPRIO;
begin
  H := THTTPRIO.Create(self);
  H.HTTPWebNode.OnBeforePost := HTTPRIO1HTTPWebNode1BeforePost;
  try 
    C := GetConsultaSpcScWSService(false,'',H);
    F := filtroConsultaSpcPlusMasterProtestoSCWS2.Create;
    try
      F.cpfCnpj := 'xxxx';
      R := C.SPCPlusMasterProtestoSC_65(f);
      Memo1.Text :=  R.consumidor.nome;
      R.free;
    finally
      C := nil;
      F.free;     
    end;
  except on E:exception do
    Memo1.Text := 'Erro :'+E.Message;
  end;
end;

procedure TForm3.HTTPRIO1HTTPWebNode1BeforePost(
  const HTTPReqResp: THTTPReqResp; Data: Pointer);
var auth:string;
begin
  auth := 'Authorization: Basic ' + EncodeString('user:pass');
  HttpAddRequestHeaders(Data, PChar(auth), Length(auth), HTTP_ADDREQ_FLAG_ADD);
end;
```

**Grato desde já.**

Comment: Olá pessoal, uma informação a mais: Utilizei um componente de terceiro no qual foi alterado o componente HTTPRio, ao realizar alguns teste com esse componente desabilitei uma opção chamada "AllowCookies", após desabilitar essa opção funcionou perfeitamente. Cheguei a conclusão então que o problema é com o armazenamento dos cookies na navegação. O problema agora é como limpar os cookies, sendo que no componente nativo HTTPRIO não possui essa propriedade (AllowCookies); Alguma sugestão? Obrigado!

Comment: de onde vem o HttpAddRequestHeaders ?
e o HTTP_ADDREQ_FLAG_ADD

Comment: Ambos vem da API do windows.

Uses: Winapi.WinInet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problema **resolvido**.
Depois de muitos testes descobri que o problema era no armazenamento dos cookies.
Para solucionar o problema simplismente limpo os cookies antes da autenticação no evento OnBeforePost do HTTPReqResp:

```
procedure TConsulta.HTTPRIO1HTTPWebNode1BeforePost(
  const HTTPReqResp: THTTPReqResp; Data: Pointer);
var
  auth:string;
  S:string;
begin
  {Clear Cookies}
  InternetSetOption(0, INTERNET_OPTION_END_BROWSER_SESSION, nil, 0);

  {autenticação, (Monta base64 e seta no Header HTTP)}
  auth := 'Authorization: Basic ' + EncodeString(GEntidade+':'+GUser + ':'+ GPassWord);
  HttpAddRequestHeaders(Data, PChar(auth), Length(auth), HTTP_ADDREQ_FLAG_ADD);
end;
```

**Talvez ajude alguém também.**